# A doubt in biotech question

Tags: biotechnology

Which type of gene does not occur naturally in living organisms?

1. Bt gene
2. Endogenous cytoplasmic defense gene

The answer is 2.

I can't find out what this gene is! Does it mean the gene for methylation and restriction enzyme synthesis or some such thing? Does it even exist?

P.s. I am just a student and do not have in-depth knowledge of biotech.

Comment: where does this question come from? "Bt gene" seems to have something to do with transgenic corn https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef130

Answer (score 3):

Endogenous just means that it is naturally occurring in the organism:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/endogenous

endogenous cytoplasmic defense gene is a general description of a gene that is cytoplasmic and whose function is defending the organism. There isn't THE Endogenous cytoplasmic defense gene. There are many endogenous cytoplasmic defense genes. Note that it is the protein coded in the gene that is cytoplasmic, not the gene itself. It should say 'gene for endogenous cytoplasmic defense protein'.

Comment: Cytoplasmic gene means plasmid and stuff?

Comment: Why is the answer that if it does occur in organisms?